# How to get Wifi working on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.10

I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a Lenovo P50.

During the installation, the wifi just worked.  The ethernet was not plugged in at this time, and all updates were via wifi.

As requested, the wifi info script was run and the results posted here:

http://pastebin.com/kkkYKJJw

Some bits are missing, as the machine is currently running Fedora.  If necessary I could boot Ubuntu Live to do other checks, but so far Fedora 25 is the only desktop distribution I had tried where both multiple displays and wifi work.

Following the install I plugged in the ethernet, and ran updates.
  sudo apt update

Now that Ubuntu is installed, I cannot get the wifi to work. The 'connect' button in the network manager is grayed out.

I have spent a couple hours trying to find a solution to this with no success.

Some new info:  I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.10. Curiously the Wifi did not work this time during the install.

So now I have rebooted into Ubuntu Live again, this time first unplugging the ethernet cable.

This time Wifi worked.  Somehow the presence of the ethernet connection is preventing the wifi from working.

lshw shows nearly the same output now,  the difference being that the wireless card is no longer disabled, and the MAC now appears.

```
# lshw -c network
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlp4s0
   version: 3a
   serial: f0:d5:bf:1b:42:de
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-22-generic firmware=22.361476.0 ip=192.168.1.83 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:141 memory:d4d00000-d4d01fff
```

After going through the reboot sequence several times I find this behavior is inconsistent.  Sometimes the wifi will work, most times it does not.

Following are the drivers on the system.

```
# ls -l /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1745176 Dec  1 19:56 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2351636 Jul 12 12:33 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2394060 Aug  9 06:08 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2120860 Aug 15 07:40 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
```

PCI info

```
# lspci -nnk | grep Wireless
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1130]
```

Network info

```
# lshw -c network 
  *-network DISABLED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d4d00000-d4d01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: c8:5b:76:53:a2:39
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-3 ip=192.168.1.84 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:130 memory:d5800000-d581ffff
```

RFKILL

```
# rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

When try to enable the interface:

```
# ifconfig wlp4s0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you blocked the wireless card via key combos (`Fn+F6`)? Have you tried a suspend or reboot (state changes tend to fix issues like this)? It sounds like those issues OR your network manager is corrupted. In that case I recommend installing WICD.

Comment: Wifi is not blocked via the F6 key.

Rebooting does not help.

Currently I have booted with the Live CD, and wifi is working.

What I found was that if the ethernet cable is plugged in when booting, wifi will not work.

Once I have updated my original question with some new info, I will plug in the ethernet and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the network manager OR installing a new network manager (WICD)?

Comment: No, I have not tried reinstalling the network manager. I do not know what WICD is.  Really, this should not be happening.  Currently I am going to try Fedora 24.

Comment: The wifi is one of the issues I have encountered with Ubuntu.  The other is the inability to properly handle 2 displays.  
The only usable method with Ubuntu has been to mirror the laptop display and monitor at the laptop resolution. Any other method would result in mousing errors, and extremely slow interface response.  

Fedora 24 was slightly better in that the wireless would work.  However it did not handle two displays even as well as Ubuntu.

Following that I tried Fedora 25.  While kind of fiddly, it does work, both for wifi and dual displays.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - wifi info was added

Comment: Thanks but wireless info from Fedora isn't really useful since it has a different system configuration than Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

Try making firmware version 22 unavailable. This can be done by renaming the file.

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode.disable
```

Comment: already tried that with no success